# How to "update" a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this:

```
let points = something
let obj1 = {
        points: points
}
```

The `points` value changes

```
let obj2 = {
        points: points
}
```

I want that `obj1.points` is equal to the first `points` value and `obj2.points` the second. Here's more of the code:

```
constructor($){

    let stats = $(".player-stats-info").get(0);
    let points = parseInt(stats.children[5]) || 0;
    this.rush = {
        points: points
    }

    stats = $(".player-stats-info").get(1);
    this.hikaBrain = {
        points: points
    }

    stats = $(".player-stats-info").get(2);
    this.skyWars = {
        points: points
    }

    stats = $(".player-stats-info").get(3);
    this.octogone = {
        points: points
    }

    //etc
}
```

Comment: If you create `obj2` after the value of `points` changes, you'd get that behaviour.

Comment: you can use lodash to clone the variable.

Comment: I see you reassigning the `stats` variable, but not the `points` variable, so I'm not sure what you're looking for - the `points` always stays the same given the code there, right?

Comment: That is because in my objects, `points` is not the only entry depending on the `stats` variable

Comment: You only assign to `points` once, though - it's only depending on the initial `stats` variable. Do you mean that you need to do `points = parseInt(stats.children[5]) || 0;` each time? (can you just do that, then? or is the question that you want to write less repetitive code?)

Comment: Actually, I would like to have something that looks like this: https://pastebin.com/4ZQC2n4v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a function that returns an object with the right structure:

```
const makeObj = stats => ({
  points: parseInt(Object.byString(stats.children[5], d)) || 0,
  gameCount: parseInt(Object.byString(stats.children[7], d)) || 0,
  victoryCount: parseInt(Object.byString(stats.children[9], d)) || 0,
  defeatCount: parseInt(Object.byString(stats.children[11], d)) || 0,
  gameTime: ms(Object.byString(stats.children[13], d)) || 0,
  killCount: parseInt(Object.byString(stats.children[15], d)) || 0,
  deathCount: parseInt(Object.byString(stats.children[17], d)) || 0,
});
```

Then just call `makeObj` with the `stats`:

```
this.rush = makeObj($(".player-stats-info").get(0));
this.skyWars = makeObj($(".player-stats-info").get(1));
// etc
```

Comment: But I want it reusable, I want an `obj3`, `obj4` etc.

Comment: Are you really reassigning `points` in between each object declaration? Can you post your full code so we can have an idea of what exactly you're doing?

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question, so as to make it on-topic for the site

Comment: let points = 'something';
const obj1 = {
  points
}
const obj2 = {
  get points() {
    return points;
  }
};

console.log(obj1.points);
console.log(obj2.points);

Comment: So? Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Hunam Can you post the relevant code in the question, to make it on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Is that what you want?

Comment: @Hunam You have to *actually post the code into the question itself*. Ok, I'll do it for you

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't understand you.

Comment: @Hunam See edit, what you're looking for sounds to be pretty different from what you looked to be originally asking, use a function instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you so much for taking the time for me!